# Maintain dynamic font color in the header during javascript vertical transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a different font colors in my th tags in html table in which I do want to have my function align the data vertically, but when I transforms the data to be Vertical, I LOSE that font color.

**Could have 12 different font headers dynamically generated from the database**

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/y8ct6b5u/

```
<table class=mytable>
    <th class=vertical bgcolor=#C0C0C0 align=center> <font color=#FF0000 size=2> Test this out</font>

    </th>
</table>
```

**Note:**

Font color can be something other tha "#FF0000"

Could be   #FFFFFF  or #000000   or whatever ...  thus I NEED to capture it.

**Someones fiddle that I forked:**

Someone else tried to say to do

```
newInnerDiv.css("background-color");
```

When I said that I do not want the code to be hard coded with their first/second answer of

```
newInnerDiv.css("color", "red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/p1w73oyj/

Comment: You're creating a new element and don't copy over the style? how was this ever going to work? your font element is gone after you transform so your "red"  color doesn't exist anymore. copy over that particular elements css style and add that to your .css()  options

Comment: Also, you should not use `font` tag. "The <font> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

Comment: So how do I find the font element value  that is not a sibling, right?   and then capture and copy it over?

Comment: Per below  :  But I don't want the style to be hard coded, the header could have different font colors

Comment: OP has know idea what they want....

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith    No  It is  "Keep font color"  in the title,  NOT   Hard code  font color

Comment: @BrianThornton How about get and set? Keep just asks to keep the current color. It is just a poorly worded question :/

Comment: @BrianThornton do you want during? or after? lol

Comment: Hi Adam,   yes, sorry about the wording of the question.    Yes Upon the button click I want it to find the font color and then apply that existing color as it transforms to the vertical layout

Comment: So update you question!.... Why are you telling me this?

Comment: Your font color is already hard-codded in your html `<font color=#FF0000 size=2>` please specify.

Comment: Yes but from the database it could end up generating 12 different font colors of which I want to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a CSS class to the table which contains the style attributes. As a general rule of thumb, you should never use HTML attributes like color and bgcolor. HTML is there to tell the browser what to show; how to display it (colours, sizes, formats, etc.) is CSS' task.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gb4pxfx5/1/.

Notice that I've created a CSS class called mytable which keeps the background and text colors, and since the class is kept upon transformations, the text color remains the same:

```
  table.mytable {
       background-color: #C0C0C0;
       color: #FF0000;   
  }
```

Edit: if you want to change the style dynamically, you can either use jQuery's css() method or switch between predefined CSS classes. Here's an example of the latter, from https://jsfiddle.net/9f73zmb2/:

```
var changeColor = function()
{
    table.removeClass(curr_class);
    curr_class = curr_class === 'red' ? 'orange' : 'red';
    table.addClass(curr_class);
    window.setTimeout(changeColor, 1000);
}
changeColor();
```

Comment: But I don't want the style to be hard coded,  the header could have different font colors

Comment: You don't really have to use HTML formats to ensure that the format is not hardcoded; it's still possible to use CSS. For instance, here is how to switch between different CSS classes: https://jsfiddle.net/9f73zmb2/.

If you need more fine grained control, you can also use jQuery's css() method to set properties such as color: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp.

Comment: It could be any color,  I don't want red or orange to be hard coded  I was trying to use   .css("background-color");